# onenote 2007 notebooks batch convert to onenote 2010/2013/2016

Tags: onenote

My customers have roughly 600gb (all together) worth of Onenote 2007 notebooks.
Onenote 2016 doesn't allow editting of onenote2007 format notebooks. It requires conversion.

MS doesn't provide a batch conversion utility.
MS does provide a notebook-by-notebook conversion via their UI which is clunky.
Does anyone know if I could use their Publish API to convert one notebook at a time?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj680120.aspx#ON14DevRef_Application_Functional (see Publish Method)

Comment: I found OneNote Snap-In, which can allow you to manipulate OneNote from PowerShell. I didn't make extensible investigation what this PowerShell modules can do, but I think that you can export all your OneNote data on PC with OneNote 2007 to text files, and after that import it back on target machine with OneNote 2010. Please look at link http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/196.aspx

Comment: That sounds like a great idea! Thank you George. If I can get powershell to convert them for me, it saves me building an app just for this purpose. I shall give this a go

Comment: I decided against learning powershell ... and wrote some code instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave it a go.
You can!

One can use the Publish API method from the Application2 onenote API COM object by opening a 2007 notebook and specifying the export format as PublishFormat.pfOneNote (to export as 2010+ format).

There are some limitations:

1. You can only convert a section. So your code will have to open the 2007   notebooks, find the sections, and convert one at a time.
2. Sections that have no pages will result in an error code being thrown. So do check that there are pages in the section before attempting conversion.

So, given the limitations, my conversion app will have to:

1. Loop through the notebooks in a big folder.
2. Open each notebook, iterate through each section, and convert each non-empty section into a new notebook folder.
3. Open the new notebook folder and create into it any missing sections.
4. Order the sections in the new notebook.
5. Save and close both notebooks.
6. Repeat.

Here's a partial implementation:
https://github.com/PetePeter/onenoteconverter

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how would one use the onenoteconverter? (I am only familiar with *nix stuff and have a lot of my kid's stuff in an older version of OneNote.)

Comment: No need. On a whim I checked my junk pile and found a copy of OneNote 2003 with license key, so I am able to access all the data now!

Comment: Gday. Yay license key. Sorry, this converter i had only ever tested going from onenote 2007 to onenote 2010+ And .. eventually when i finished it somewhere, i ended up not using to convert anything.